# Removing preallocating warning when preallocating is done in another file

Tags: matlab, allocation

I have some parameters changing size on every loop iteration in main.m. I have placed the preallocations in another script called preallocation.m.

When the preallocations is placed in another script, I get a warning from Matlab for every parameter in the main script about concidering preallocating for improved speed.

Is there a way to remove these warnings? If I add another parameter that needs preallocating and forget to preallocate, I'd like to get a warning for that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to make your preallocation script a function. Then you could write something like

```
[myvar1,myvar2,myvar3] = preallocate();
```

This would allow you to see all preallocated variables at a glance and would also keep mlint quiet.

Comment: I'm preallocating in another file in order to improve cleanliness. Making my preallocation script a function would reduce the cleanliness due to a large amount of outputs, wouldn't it?

Comment: I prefer allocations to be explicit...it helps show what you've done.

Comment: I'd make them all functions....  It will be better in the long term.  Its a nightmare debugging (someone else's or your own old code) where variables are modified in other scripts which in turn may call other scripts etc.....  Its a common source of potential errors

Answer (score 0):

In my MATLAB version (R2014b) this is done by right-clicking on the variable that has the squiggly red line onder it, and then selection the option  `Suppress "The variable myVar appears to..."`. You can then choose to suppress this single line, all warnings of this type in the entire file, or all warnings of this type in all files.

edit: if your MATLAB version does not have this context menu option, you can add `%#ok<SAGROW>` to the end of the offending line, like so:

```
someVar(ii+1) = someVar(ii) + someConstant;    %#ok<SAGROW>
```

If you are hell-bent on not wanting these warnings and not using a preallocation function that returns many variables, you could also do the following:

```
function init = preallocate()
    init.a = some stuff;
    init.b = some stuff;
    ...
end

%% actual script
init = preallocate()
structvars(init);       % using structvars from file exchange
```

`structvars` can be found [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26216-structure-fields-to-variables). Note that I haven't tried the package myself, so I am unsure as to how well it will work and how fast it is.

Comment: So Matlab cannot check for preallocations in files mentioned in the main.m? Your solution works, but it is not ideal. If I need to comment on the same line, I must do it after the "%#ok<SAGROW>". What's more, I don't know if all variables on the line are preallocated or not. The preallocation check for a line is, as far as I can see, disabled when using "%#ok<SAGROW>".

Comment: You could create a preallocation function that returns a single structure with all the variables you need and then replace your variable names with the `struct.varname` variant. In general, I would only place a single assignment on a single line of code, so the 'all variables being preallocated' issue should not arise in that way.